# React Native UI Kitten: Difficult to click <Tab> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabview, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm using UI Kitten `<Tab/>` in my React Native app, and it's difficult to click. It seems as though only a tiny fraction of the tab at the bottom is actually clickable. My code is:

```
import { Layout, Tab, TabView } from '@ui-kitten/components';
...
<TabView>
  <Tab title="Title">
    ...
  </Tab>
  <Tab title="Title">
    ...
  </Tab>
</TabView>
```

I found that if I added `<Tab title="Title" style={{height: '100%'}}>` it does make it easier to press, but it's then much taller than I want.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

**SOLUTION:**

It was an error elsewhere in my code. I had a component with opacity 0 sitting in front of the tabs.